# Windows Phone 8 Translator App Throws Errors

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012, azure, windows-phone-8, translation

So I followed all the directions exactly on MSDN's http://blogs.msdn.com/b/translation/p/windowsphone8.aspx tutorial page for using the translator. I am debugging it on my device. It loads up on my phone and I can type in the text. Once I hit translate nothing happens at all. Just does not do anything. I did update the client id and client secret to what it says on my account information for the registered app. I know this is correct, because if I type it in differently it throws errors and crashes the program.

The console output while the program is running (Hitting translate) is as follow:

> An exception of type
>   'System.Runtime.Serialization.InvalidDataContractException' occurred
>   in System.Runtime.Serialization.ni.dll and wasn't handled before a
>   managed/native boundary
>       A first chance exception of type 'System.Runtime.Serialization.InvalidDataContractException' occurred
>   in System.ServiceModel.Web.ni.dll
>       An exception of type 'System.Runtime.Serialization.InvalidDataContractException' occurred
>   in System.ServiceModel.Web.ni.dll and wasn't handled before a
>   managed/native boundary

Comment: Exception clearly says that your app fails serialization. Do you have any properties/methods, which can't be serialized (i.e., is a method or does not contain `DataMember` attribute), in a class, you're trying to serialize?

Comment: Its literally an exact copy of the code in the link. I added in my client id and secret key.

Comment: In general, classes that are used for serialize/deserialize like this should be marked by `DataContract` and properties that are serialized with `DataMember` attributes. Not sure, why it's omitted in example. I'd decorate `AdmAccessToken` class with them and try it.

Comment: It is not seeming to recognize the [DataContract] and [DataMember] tags.

Comment: Nevermind I included the "System.Runtime.Serialization" library, and then it allowed me to to put those tags. I decorated the class as you suggested, and it seemed to fix the errors, and the app is translating fine now. Thank you!

Comment: You're welcome. Glad that I helped you. I am just curious why that is omitted in example, weird.